# WCF Authentication doesn't prompt for credentials

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I've created a test WCF app in which I'm trying to get Authentication to work, but it just runs my method and doesn't ask me to login / authenticate. Below is code snippets in my web.config in my WCF app:

```
<bindings>
       <wsHttpBinding>
           <binding name="Binding1">
               <security mode="Message">
                   <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
               </security>
           </binding>
       </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<serviceCredentials>
         <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyAPI.Authorization, App_Code" />
</serviceCredentials>
```

My Authorization class:

```
public class Authorization : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (null == userName || null == password)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            if (!(userName == "test1" && password == "1tset") && !(userName == "test2" && password == "2tset"))
            {
                // This throws an informative fault to the client.
                throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
                // When you do not want to throw an infomative fault to the client,
                // throw the following exception.
                // throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
            }
        }
    }
```

My Service.svc.cs Class

```
public string Hello(string message)
{
     return "You typed: " + message;
}
```

Am I supposed to put some attribute above this method to require authentication or above the class?

I have then created a Test Console Application, here is the code:

```
public static Test.Service1Client client = new Test.Service1Client();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(client.Hello("hello"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

This just outputs "You typed: hello" without asking for authentication. Here is snippets of my app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://MyServer/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="Test.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

I would expect to have to set the login credentials before calling `client.Hello("hello")` by doing:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test1";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "1tset";
```

But obviously not

## Edit

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Binding1">
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceCredentials>
  <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyAPI.Authorization, App_Code" />
</serviceCredentials>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Typically client such as browser would prompt for credentials. Your test console application would not prompt because u haven't coded it that way. Said that service call should have failed if you have not supplied the credentials. Check if you have bound the service with the Binding1 biding in server config.

Comment: @VinayC - Where do I see that? See my edit, it contains my whole web.config file from my service

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the wrong bindings, the client is using BasicHttpBinding while you defined a WsHttpBinding on the server.

Answer (score 0):

WCF/IIS will magically wire up services you have without the need for configuration (can't remember the name of this functionality offhand...). However, you're defining some custom binding configuration - that's fine, but you need to tell your service to use this.

You need to add a `<service>` element to you server's config, something like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   ...
   <services>
      <service name="FullClassNameOfYourService">
         <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding"
                   bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
                   contract="FullClassNameOfYourServiceContract" />
      </service>
   </services>
```

Also, the fact that your client config doesn't contain a `wsHttpBinding` element suggests that HTTPS is not enabled for the website hosting your service.

Comment: I now get: The contract name 'MyAPI.IService1' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Service1'.

Comment: Is the value of the `name` attribute just "Serivce1"? Based on your contract type, I think the service name should be "MyAPI.Service1" - the class name needs the namespace as well.

Comment: I have this set: `<service name="MyAPI.Service1">
                <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding"
                          bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
                          contract="MyAPI.IService1" />`

Comment: hmm, you may need to post your service contract interface and service implementation class in your question, I'm a bit confused!

Comment: I changed it to: `<service name="Service1">
                <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding"
                          bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
                          contract="IService1" />` and the error goes but I still can't authenticate, I can still run `client.Hello("Hello")` without passing any authentication details

Comment: So do I need to enable HTTPS for this to work? Can't I get it to work without HTTPS for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Your userNameAuthentication is incorrect. customUserNamePasswordValidatorType must be of the form "[fully qualified assembly+classname], [namespace]". I can't tell what your namespace is from your post, but something like:

```
<userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
 customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyNamespace.Authorization , MyNamespace" />
```

As others have said, your client must be using the same binding type to connect to the service.

Also, on your server side, you've set Security Mode to none, yet you have a transport and a message tag. Within the security tag. Any Transport and Message security specifications are ignored if you're doing None as your security. In other words, with security mode of None, your client credential type is disregarded, and thus clients do not have to authenticate.

Comment: I've tried that but it kept throwing an error so thats why I put my Authorization class inside App_Code and used that, it worked! I've now put the security type to Transport and set the same binding type on both client and server (both using basicHttpbinding) but I get the following error: `The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
Parameter name: via`

Comment: "an error" doesn't help me much. How do you know that putting it in App_Code works if you're getting a different error? if it's looking for https, that seems to indicate that you've specified Transport level security.

Comment: by "an error", I mean it was throwing an error until I changed it to use App_Code, then it "worked", ie didnt throw an error, but thats not the problem here

Answer (score 0):

You use WCF 4 which has a simplified config file. It has its merits but it is harder to debug it. I suspect your custom wshttpbinding is not applied. Try a more verbose configutation (like wcf 3.5):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfService6.Service1Behavior"
        name="WcfService6.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
          contract="WcfService6.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService6.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```